# How to replace current row value based on current minus previous row same column value in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Input :

| Count | Time ms |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 12 |
| 500 | 18 |
| 600 | 25 |

Output:

| Count | Time ms |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 12 |
| 300 | 6 |
| 100 | 7 |

Sample input.csv:

```
Count,Time  
200,12  
500,18  
600,25
```

Comment: can you share the input file? is it supposed to be a csv file?

Comment: yes a csv file with "," delimiter

Comment: please share some sample of the file in the expected csv format si it's easier for people seeing the question to offer a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use awk:

```sh
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2-p}{p=$2}' file.csv
```

NR is a row number. $2 refers to the second column (columns are separated by `,`). FS and OFS variables controls the input and output delimiters.

See the [link](https://www.tecmint.com/awk-built-in-variables-examples/) for the examples.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Volkovsky, works well !